# ':leave' transition does not fire in Angular 2+ App

Tags: angular, animation, transition

I tried a simple animation using @angular/animations module to make a welcome-text fade in and out again.
The fade-in effect (:enter transition) works just fine but the :leave transition does not fire. I cannot see why it is not working. Please help :)

I tried both ways of defining the transition (':leave' or '* => void') nothing works.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-welcome',
  templateUrl: './welcome.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./welcome.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('fade', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(4000, style({ opacity: 1 })),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate(4000, style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ]),
    ]
})
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The Welcome text is supposed to fade in after a few seconds and fade out again after a few seconds. Fade in works, fade out not.

Template:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">

              <span class="font-weight-bold" @fade style="font-size:6vw;"> W E L C O M E !</span>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the start and end styles for the transition.

```
  transition(':leave', [
    style({ opacity: 1 }),
    animate(4000, style({ opacity: 0 }))
  ])
```

If you want the value to be dynamic for the starting style, then use a `*` value.

```
  transition(':leave', [
    style({ opacity: '*' }),
    animate(4000, style({ opacity: 0 }))
  ])
```

Comment: thanks for your help. unfortunately it doesn't change anything. maybe something is wrong in the template?

Answer (score 0):

The `:leave` will get triggered when the element is hidden. Sample stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxt5w9

Comment: thanks but I want it to appear and disappear automatically without any events involved. How can I do that?

Comment: You can add multiple `animate` in a single transition, check the updated the example.

Comment: thank you so much. this helps a lot! one last question: if I want the welcome to be fully and automatically removed after it vanishes (I do not want it to be displayed again after the animation as it is now) how can I do that?

Comment: What you need to to is this: animate when the element is displayed `:enter` transition. When this animation is finished, hide the element (trigger the `:leave` animation). Updated the stackblitz also